# How can I make my bottom pop-up bar closable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I created a pop-up on my website using HTML for alerts that goes on the bottom of the screen. Here's what I have so far:

```
<div id="toolbar" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; color: #fff; background: #000;">
     <p><b>ATTENTION:</b> Text Here </p>
</div>
```

It's a good bar, but I can't figure out how to make it be able to be closed.

Comment: What do you mean by closed ?

Comment: What Javascript/jQuery have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried changing divs property `display` to hide the div for example? Btw how do u manage this thing to popup, I mean if it's popup.. it should popup and pop back, right?

Answer (score 2):

**jQuery way:** 
HTML:

```
<div id="toolbar" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; color: #fff; background: #000;">
    <p><b>ATTENTION:</b> Text Here </p>
    <span id="close">x</span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
  $('#close').on('click', function() {
    $('#toolbar').hide();
  })
</script>
```

**Pure JavaScript way:**

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("toolbar").style.display = 'none';
  });
</script>
```

You create "X" inside your popup and when clicked, it hides popup.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`onclick()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) event and javascript function:

```js
function hide() {
  document.getElementById('toolbar').style.display = 'none'; //gets the element and sets display to none
}
```

```html
<div id="toolbar" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; color: #fff; background: #000;">
         <p><b>ATTENTION:</b> Text Here </p>
  <div onclick="hide();" style="text-align: center">&times;</div>
</div>
```

Or easier:

```
<div onclick="document.getElementById('toolbar').style.display = 'none';">&times;</div>
```